# Getting "Cannot find module '/app/dist'" error on deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, babeljs

I have the following script in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2",
    "build": "babel ./server -d ./dist",
    "start": "node ./dist",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd react-ui/ && npm install && npm install    --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
```

On deploying to Heroku I get the following error

`Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist'`

On local `npm run dev`, `npm run build`, and `npm run start` work fine.

Where is it getting the /app folder? How to fix this?

Thanks
Matloob

Comment: try running bash on heroku and type npm run build there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should build your app `npm run build` before deploy to `heroku`. It will run `heroku-postbuild` first then `start` your app.

Comment: I was building my app before deploying to Heroku, but I had added `dist` to .gitignore. :face_palm:

Thanks @Tuấn Trần Duy

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

"start:heroku": "node dist/YOUR-APP-NAME/server/main.js",

Comment: It's exactly like that, but, not works. :s